# Тебе стоит также собрать пару каштанов(,) кроме этих кленовых листочков

Tags: запятые

Мы знаем, что, даже когда *кроме* имеет в виду *помимо*, запятая обязательна всегда, в начале оно или посерёдке стоит. Но если оно, **в значении *помимо* используясь**, стоит в конце? Запятая необязательна?

> Тебе стоит также собрать пару каштанов(,) кроме этих кленовых листочков.

Comment: И у _кроме_, и у _помимо_ те же два значения. Это одинаковые два предлога. Одно значение — значение добавления, второе — исключения.

Comment: А как можно из пары каштанов исключить кленовые листочки?  Никак не могу догадаться.  Контекст нужен, КРОМЕ правил.

Comment: _Клиновый_ от слова _клин_? Исправил ваш вопрос.

Comment: Задача: От пяти каштанов отнимите три листочка. Сколько каштанов и листочков получится?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Тебе стоит также собрать пару каштанов кроме этих кленовых листочков* — ’наряду с этими кленовыми листочками’.

*Тебе стоит также собрать пару каштанов, кроме этих кленовых листочков* — ’собрать каштаны, а кленовые листочки не собрать’.

Подробнее [здесь, во 2-м пункте](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=116).

Запятая / отсутствие запятой показывает смысл дополнения.

Comment: А если я поставлю запятую, то ошибка будет? Это предложение без запятой выглядит несколько монотонно и неестественно. И какой там может быть разный смысл. И так понятно: листики собраны, надо еще пару каштанов для икебаны добавить. It's utter nonsense to look for meaning here.

Answer (score 0):

**ИКЕБАНА (правильное решение)**

(1) *Тебе стоит также собрать пару каштанов, **кроме этих кленовых листочков.***

Значение **включения**. Собирать надо и каштаны, и листья, это **единое множество.**

(2)  *Тебе стоит собрать **еще что-то** (каштаны, камешки, прутики), **кроме этих кленовых листочков.***

Значение **исключения**. Собирать надо что-то ещё, но только **не кленовые листочки** (их уже достаточно). Из множества (еще что-то) нади **исключить** листочки.

**ТЕОРИЯ**

1. Есть множество, к которому мы добавляем или из которого исключаем еще один член. **Его надо правильно обозначить!**

Практически в большинстве случаев обороты со значением включения/исключения **обособляются**, но не всегда.

2. **Значение исключения:**

Тут, **кроме небольшого столика**, не было никакой мебели. Все принимали участие в разговоре, **кроме Кити и Левина**. Дом, **кроме этой комнаты,** стоял заколоченный.

Но: *Я встаю из-за стола. **Кроме меня** тут дверь открыть некому.*

3. **Включение:**

**Кроме старика**, в этот день приходило к нам ещё двое. **Кроме трубки**, у вас, может быть, есть и папиросы?

Но: **Кроме зарплаты** они получают и премиальные.  **Кроме рисунков** были приложены ещё чертежи. **Кроме хозяев** в комнате были и гости. **Кроме вашей химии** существуют ведь и другие науки.

4. **Определять смысл оборота по запятым?** Это возможно крайне редко. Никто этим и не занимается. В текстах **из Нацкорпуса** эти обороты обособляются **факультативно**, как и обстоятельственные обороты. Многое зависит от структуры предложения.

**Смысл оборота**  практически всегда можно определить **по контексту.**

Comment: Давайте признаем, что оба ответа (и ваш, и мой) по сути верны.

Comment: Никаких компромиссов!))  (1)  Запятая нужна!  (2) Второе предложение (исключение) понимается некорректно.  Мы не можем исключать листочки из каштанов) (3) Практика показывает: оборот обособляется факультативно, хотя чаще обособляется.

Comment: Почему? Мало ли что он имел в виду! Поэтому по смыслу модно ставить, а можно и нет. И, знаете ли, не надо говорить такие категоричные вещи, где "никто не будет определять смысл по запятым, это утопия и т. д." якобы. Можно или нельзя исключить — это уже автор решает! И такие категоричные вещи говорить нельзя. То, что в моëм ответе, зафиксировано в справочнике Розенталя, не я это придумал. Так с чего нельзя этим пользоваться, объясните мне? Это в официальном справочнике, ещë как можно и нужно!! Свои правила тоже устанавливать нельзя!

Comment: Налеюсь, вы подумаете над всем сообщением, а ре только над последним предложением. А вы-то можете запросто так!!

Comment: Максим, а я же не вам лично про утопию говорю.  Я долго изучала эту тему, по ней задавались другие вопросы, в Нацкорусе много примеров. Я обобщаю всю информацию, которая у меня есть.  У Розенталя смысл оговаривается в очень частных примерах, это редкость. Ну и в целом. Неужели вы, читая книгу,  будете определять смысл по запятым? Нет, конечно, Смысл ясен из контекста, а запятые нужна для удобства чтения.  Отсюда категоричность.  Правила правилами, а практика вносит свои коррективы. Извините, если я вас обидела, надеялась на ваше чувство юмора.

Comment: И какой мне смысл устанавливать свои правила, Я решаю задачи и делюсь с вами своими впечатлениями, надеясь на дружественную аудиторию.  Это методика решения задач в соответствии с правилами  Розенталя.  Но жизнь не стоит на месте,  иногда детализация правил кажется лишней.  И сам Розенталь говорил о ГИБКОСТИ пунктуации.  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=85#pp85

Comment: Особенности русской пунктуации — в присущей ей многофункциональности знаков препинания и широкой их взаимозаменяемости, в своеобразии индивидуально-авторского использования знаков препинания, в гибкости пунктуационной системы, позволяющей выявлять не только смысловую сторону текста, но и стилистические его оттенки. Все это исключает формальный подход к соблюдению правил.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, вот это уже по-нашему. Конечно, вряд ли кто-то будет определять смысл по запятым, но почему всë же нельзя по смыслу обособлять? Да, никто не будет по запятым определять, но всë же. По поводу вашего ответа к монему вопросу: я пока ещë почитаю про единый знак, а потом решу.

Comment: Автор видит в своем тексте значение включения.  И спрашивает о позиции оборота. Почему он думает, что позиция оборота влияет  на постановку запятой? Вероятно думает, что ударение переходит на конец оборота и смысл может измениться.  Но у этих оборотов смысл определяется иначе

Comment: ,.А как именно?

Comment: I don't like the answer.

Comment: Ну спасибо за минусовку, сэр. А я так старалась...  Знали бы вы, сколько времени потратила! Но не жалею, нет!  В теме стала намного лучше разбираться. Множество – это мое маленькое открытие.  И всё для себя, другим-то ничего не надо. Впредь уж отвечать не буду.  Ну да вы не много потеряете...

Comment: Не знаю, с минусом ответа Леопольд погорячился, мне кажется. Вродь нормальный ответ.

Comment: Не знаю, но минусовка ответа на СВОЙ вопрос  – дело серьезное. Такое не часто встречается.  По-моему,  практически не встречается совсем.