# О значении исключения для предлога "кроме"

Tags: семантика, предлоги

(1) Дано предложение: *Тебе стоит также собрать пару каштанов(,) **кроме этих кленовых листочков.***

Дано **пояснение**: собрать каштаны, а кленовые листочки не собрать.

(2) Это значение **исключения** (листочки надо исключить)? Но как можно исключить листочки из каштанов?

(3) Вопрос: Возможно ли здесь **значение исключения** для предлога КРОМЕ? Я полагаю, что **только включение** (от запятой решение не зависит): собрать и листочки, и каштаны.

Может быть, надо **изменить** предложение, чтобы предлог КРОМЕ имел значение **исключения.**

А как вы думаете?

Вопрос **[по теме](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476247/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2)**

Comment: Дано пояснение: собрать каштаны, а кленовые листочки не собрать. - пропущено условие "еще и".  собрать **еще и** каштаны, а кленовые листочки не собрать. А листочки ты уже собрал.

Comment: Этот структурный элемент дополнительно проясняет  значение оборота)

Comment: Вы забываете о временном контексте. Эта фраза говориться после просьбы собрать или факта собранных листочков. Вырываете из контекста условие.

Comment: Может быть.  Но вы мне лучше про множество скажите. Можно из каштанов листочки вычитать или нет? В литературных примерах при исключении всегда есть бОльшее множество: стул и мебель, все и двое, дом и комната. Или напрасно я так думаю,  и всё в теме у них ОК?  Сложить листочки и каштаны можно, а как вычесть – не знаю.

Comment: Наверное, это кривое исключение, потому что это и то и другое, а принесли только "и то". То есть множество было "и то и другое", а теперь нужно "и другое".

Comment: Очень КРИВОЕ и непонятное, если вообще было) И я им сразу говорила: нельзя листья из каштанов "честь". В общем, тему прикрыли, никому она не интересна.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, на слух в этом предложении никак нельзя исключение почувствовать — надо писать следующим образом (где *кроме* — это *помимо*):

> Тебе стоит также собрать пару каштанов кроме/помимо этих кленовых листочков.

Если же надо исключение показать, то стоит использовать *за исключением*, и запятая, в соответствии с Лопатиным, факультативна (http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122), но я бы её поставил.

> Тебе стоит также собрать пару каштанов(,) за исключением этих кленовых листочков.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение. Некорректность  по слуху я определила сразу, сложнее было с некорректностью по смыслу. Нужно еще обратить внимание на будущее время для данной ситуации.  Клиновые листочки уже были изначально или нет? Их нужно еще собирать или нет? А это уже разный смысл (включение или исключение).

Comment: *Кленовые* они же.

Comment: А у меня – клиновые! Остренькие такие – и колются. В летне-осенне-зимнем лесу их много. Осторожно с ними надо...  http://vsegda-pomnim.com/uploads/posts/2022-04/1649558168_31-vsegda-pomnim-com-p-raznovidnosti-klena-foto-32.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Дело было так.

Нужно было собрать природные материалы **для осенней композиции,** и мы с Машей пошли в парк.

**Ситуация 1. У нас пока ничего нет.**

*— Ты что хочешь собрать?*

*— Кленовые листочки!*

*— Тебе стоит также собрать пару каштАнов, **кроме этих кленовых листОчков.***

Это значение только включения: надо собрать и каштаны, и листочки.

Оборот явно имеет **УТОЧНЯЮЩЕЕ** значение, запятая ставится:  **нельзя собрать каштаны помимо листочков!** Их можно собрать **в дополнение** к листочкам, наряду с листочками. Но это не основная информация, почему ее нужно включать в основное сообщение?

**Ситуация 2. У нас дома уже есть листочки.**

*— Ты что хочешь собрать?*

*— Кленовые листочки!*

*— Тебе стоит собрать  что-нибудь **ДРУГОЕ** (каштаны, камешки, прутики, **кроме кленовых листочков.** Ведь листочки у нас уже есть.*

Это значение **исключения.**

Таким образом семантику мы определяем **по контексту**. Что же касается обособления, то оборот в обоих значениях чаще обособляется. Это практика письма, и это мнение Розенталя. Нет обособления в нераспространенных предложениях.

**Значение исключения** для предлога ***КРОМЕ*** (за исключением) вполне **возможно:**

**Исключение.** Тут, кроме небольшого столика, не было никакой мебели. Все принимали участие в разговоре, кроме Кити и Левина. Дом, кроме этой комнаты, стоял заколоченный.

**Включение.** Кроме старика, в этот день приходило к нам **ещё** двое. Кроме трубки, у вас, может быть, есть **и** папиросы?